# Volume form on $S^n$ is $SO(n+1)$ - invariant

Tags: differential-geometry

For $a=(a_1, \cdots, a_{n+1})\in S^n$, and $v_i=(v_{i,1}, \cdots, v_{i,n+1}) \in T_aS^n, \ 1 \leq i \leq n$. We define the volume form $\omega$ as $$\omega(a)(v_1,\cdots,v_n)=\det \begin{pmatrix}a_1&\dots & a_{n+1}\\v_{1,1}&\dots & v_{1,n+1} \\ \vdots &  & \vdots\\v_{n,1}&\dots & v_{n,n+1}\end{pmatrix}$$

How do I show that this volume from is $SO(n+1)$ - invariant?

Differential geometry isn't my forté, so if I could get some idea on what techniques to employ to arrive at an answer, I'll be obliged. Any small hints/nudges are much appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that the derivative of a linear map $x \to gx$ is just $g$ itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Would you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You're basically computing the Jacobian of the map $x \to gx$ for $g\in SO(n+1)$.

Comment: Though it's already given that $\omega$ is a volume form, I'm trying to prove it. Any hints on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $g^*\omega_a(V_1,...,V_n)=det(g(a),g(V_1),...,g(V_n))=det(g)det(a,V_1,...,V_n)$, use the fact that $det(g)=1$.